# float: right для блока

Tags: html, css

Верстаю такой макет http://www.freepsd.ws/75-kulinarnyy-psd-maket-fastyfood.html, для правого блока #sidebar задаю float: right, но так как контент занимает не всю высоту блока, то когда контент в сайдбаре заканчивается, то блок дольше не отображается [link text](http://web-portfolio1.narod.ru/index4/index.html)
Как задать высоту сайдбара не зависимо от высоты контента? min-height: 100% и height: 100% не помогли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, что бы min-height: 100% и height: 100% работали, у родителя должна быть выставлена высота отличная от auto;

Когда пытаемся сайт растянуть на всю высоту мы что делаем ? Устанавливает height: 100% и блоку, и body, и html.

Так как не всегда есть возможность задать определенную высоту родительскому блоку, то для решения вот такой задачи (разделение сайта на 2 колонки выделенные разными цветами, но одинаковой высоты) можно использовать картинку. Вырежьте картинку высотой в 1px и шириной  равной правой колонке. Положите на бэкграунд родительскому блоку и спозиционируйте под правую колонку. Задайте repeat-y бэкграунду. Так получится визуально 2 колонки. А Реальная правая колонка будет с прозрачным фоном и меньшей высоты (по контенту), но это никого не будет напрягать.

В вашем примере:

```
#main {background: url('картинка с серым фоном') 663px 0 repeat-y #fff;}
#sidebar {background:none;}
```

Comment: а вариант, который далее предложили, через плагин jQuery, выравнивающий высоту блоков, будет хорошим решением в таком случае или нет?

Comment: Я считаю его плохим в данном случае из-за того, что можно обойтись без яваскрипта и не вижу смысла его применения в данном случае. Нам нет нужды иметь физически одинаковые колонки одной высоты. Нам надо визуально подать их выделив цветом. Это можно сделать средствами css и картинкой. Нагружать лишними скриптами где этого можно избежать не лучший опыт :) При этом могут возникнуть ситуации, когда колонки загрузятся разной высоты , а потом выровняются и пользователь увидит прыгающий момент.

Comment: понятно, спасибо, сейчас попробую сделать картинкой. а из-за чего при использовании плагина могут возникнуть ситуации,когда колонки загрузятся разной высоты , а потом выровняются и пользователь увидит прыгающий момент?

Answer (score 1):

если я правильно понял, то тебе нужно выровнить эти оба блока по высоте...то есть [такое решение](http://ruseller.com/adds.php?rub=11&id=2483)

Comment: спасибо, пригодится)